# How to display the Plots by executing the file from command line

Tags: julia

I'm trying to execute the below code that display a plot:

```
using Plots, Measures
pyplot()

data = [rand(100), rand(100)];

histogram(data, layout = 2,
          title = ["Dataset A" "Dataset B"], legend = false,
          ylabel = "ylabel", margin = 5mm)
```

I do not get any output once I execute it from the command line!!

[image]

Knowing that I tried it in 3 different ways and it works (Jupyter, Juni, Julia session), though I'm confused about the way it works in the `Juno`, kinldy see my observations below:

With `Jupyter` it is functioning perfectly:

With Juno, I've to run the file TWICE!! the first time looks to be for compilation, second time for execution, maybe!!
And if I closed the plot, I've to close the Julia session, restart it, then re-execute the file TWICE!! and sometimes nothing is appearing!!

With Julia session, it take time for first time execution, then if I closed the plot and run it again, it is appearing smoothly.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't post the same question on multiple forums without at least crosslink them: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-display-the-plots-by-executing-the-file-from-command-line/13822

Comment: @fredrikekre multiple platforms could have different audience,

Comment: Yes, but as I said, at least post links in between them, and be open about that you asked the same question elsewhere. Otherwise people waste their time answering questions that are already answered elsewhere.

Comment: I see my friend, @fredrikekre from your feedbacks ppl will understood it is already answered somewhere else, while actually no answer yet provided, in any of the platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commands like `histogram` or `plot` typically don't display the plots for users, they only generate and return the plots.
What displays the plots is actually the display system in Julia.
When Julia is in interactive use, like in REPL, Jupyter and Juno, the display system will be invoked automatically with commands not ending with ";". That's why you see plots displayed in REPL, Jupyter and Juno.
But when executing the file from the command line, the display system is not automatically activated. So you first have to invoke `display` yourself like this:

```
using Plots, Measures
pyplot()

data = [rand(100), rand(100)];

h = histogram(data, layout = 2,
              title = ["Dataset A" "Dataset B"], legend = false,
              ylabel = "ylabel", margin = 5mm)
display(h)
```

But even this will not give you the picture, but only text representation of the plot. This is because in command line julia, only a very simple text display system is in place, and it doesn't have "full" support for plots from `Plots`. To display the plots, you have to write your own display mechanism and push it to Julia display system, which is not hard but a little tedious. I will give an example when I have more time.

BTW, if you just want plots generated from command line, another way is to save it to files, which is more direct than making a display mechanism yourself.

### Update

Here is a simple display, which mimics the display system used in Julia REPL. The code here is for Julia 0.7/1.0.

```
const output = IOBuffer()
using REPL
const out_terminal = REPL.Terminals.TerminalBuffer(output)
const basic_repl = REPL.BasicREPL(out_terminal)
const basic_display = REPL.REPLDisplay(basic_repl)
Base.pushdisplay(basic_display)
```

Using it before the previous code will show the plot. Please note that you use `pyplot()` backend for `Plots`, whose default is to open a new window and display the plot in the window, but when the julia finish execution in the command line, it will close the plot window. To deal with this, we could either change ways for the default display, or use another backend to show the plot, for example, `plotly()` backend will display the plot through html. The complete code may look like following:

```
const output = IOBuffer()

using REPL

const out_terminal = REPL.Terminals.TerminalBuffer(output)

const basic_repl = REPL.BasicREPL(out_terminal)

const basic_display = REPL.REPLDisplay(basic_repl)

Base.pushdisplay(basic_display)

using Plots, Measures
plotly()

data = [rand(100), rand(100)];

h = histogram(data, layout = 2,
          title = ["Dataset A" "Dataset B"], legend = false,
          ylabel = "ylabel", margin = 5mm)

display(h)
```

Comment: Thanks, the option with `plotly()` worked perfectly, for the first option I tried using `gr()` then the `GKS` icon appeared in the menu bar, but the dialog had not been displayed, I linked your answer to `Julia community` https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-display-the-plots-by-executing-the-file-from-command-line/13822/2

Comment: How can I save the generated output - html file?

Comment: The html file generated by `plotly()` should have a menu bar which you can save the picture. The whole html itself should be in some temporary folder, you can just save as the html to somewhere else if you want, for example, in chrome, it works by Right Click -> Save as.....

Comment: The `gr()` works for me. It just opens another window, show the plot, and then the window close and julia finishes execution. The whole process can be quite short... I'm on mac. Maybe it is caused by difference between platforms, configuration of GR or some problems in installation of GR.

Comment: I'm in Mac too, I minimized all the windows, and noticed the execution, it is closed extremely fast, is there a way to delay the window closer!

Comment: for `plotly()` the generated html file is path: file:///private/var/folders/wt/lxgc4mss75zftl0htqfy2n0r0000gn/T/juliatWVXGU.html is there a way within Julia code, to get copy of it to the root directory of my code?

Comment: You can add something like `sleep(time)` at the end of your julia script. This way julia will finish execution some `time` after displaying the plot. There should be a way to get the file location of the plot and copy it to somewhere else programmatically, but I'm not familiar with that. Why not just saving the plot to some file? I think function like `savefig` can do that quite easily.

Answer (score 0):

Use readline() to get such destination that close the plot window by typing enter.

```
using GR
y = rand(20,1)
p = plot(y,linewidth=2,title="My Plot")
readline()
```